# Determinar que imprimir usando wicked_pdf en ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, ruby, rubygems

Tengo una vista de los datos de una persona (datos contacto, domicilio, datos laborales, datos médicos, etc). Por el momento logro convertir en PDF todo lo que tengo en la vista, pero lo que necesito es que al presionar el botón de convertir en PDF me muestre una pantalla (puede ser un modal), donde mediante checks pueda elegir que secciones de mi vista imprimir.

Actualmente para imprimir utilizo el `def show` donde tengo definido los parámetros para convertir un archivo `list_pdf.pdf.erb` en el `pdf` con los datos de la vista.

Uso la gema `wicked_pdf` en `rails 4`.

[actualizado]

Tengo lo siguiente ...

## controller user

```
def show
          respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.pdf do
          render :pdf         => "file_name",

      end
    end
  end
```

#views/user/show.html.erb

```
<div>
            ...
            <h2><%= @user.last_name %> <%= @user.name %></h2>
            ...
        </div>
        #boton activa modal
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal">
        #el modal
        ...
          <div class="modal-body">
                          <%= form_for employee_path do %>
                              Area 1
                              <%= check_box_tag :area1 %>
                              Area 2
                              <%= check_box_tag :area2 %>

                          <% end %>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                #boton que imprime
                                 <%= link_to user_path(  format: :pdf), :target => '_blank', class: 'btn btn-default' do %>
                      Imprimir <span>
                      <i class="fa fa-print " aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <%end%>
         </div>
         ---
```

## show.pdf.erb

...

```
<% if params[:area1]%>
    <div>
            ..bloque
    </div>
    <%end%>
```

en el controller probé y no puedo recuperar el valor de params[:area1]. saludos

Comment: Ese `link_to user_path` no va a enviar los checkboxes que selecciones. Tienes que poner un `<button type="submit">Imprimir</button>` dentro del form para poder enviarlo. Además tu form debería quedar como `form_for user_path(format: :pdf)` si quieres que haga lo mismo del `link_to`. Por último el `form_for` por defecto hace un request de tipo `POST`, mientras que el `link_to` uno de tipo `GET`, así que tus opciones son: agregar la ruta `POST` correspondiente a tu `routes.rb`, dejar tu form como `form_for user_path(format: :pdf), method; :get` o simplemente crear un nuevo action para el form.

Comment: Gracias @AlterLagos , me sirvió tu ayuda, cree el fomr y un nuevo método. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nunca he hecho algo así con `wicked_pdf`, pero lo que se me ocurre es que en tu formulario tengas algo como:

```
<%= form_tag pdf_download_path do %>
  Area 1
  <%= check_box_tag 'area1' %>
  Area 2
  <%= check_box_tag 'area2' %>
  <%# etc... %>
<% end %>
```

Y luego en el template de tu pdf decidas a través de los parámetros elegidos cuál es la sección del pdf a mostrar:

```
<% if params[:area1] %>
  <%# contenido de tu area 1 del pdf %>
<% end %>
<% if params[:area2] %>
  <%# contenido de tu area 2 del pdf %>
<% end %>
<%# etc... %>
```

Para hacerlo en un modal, puedes usar los integrados en [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).
Me cuentas como te va con eso. Saludos

Comment: Buenas... gracias por responder, estaba masticando esa solución como planteaste, pero no le encuentro la vuelta de como crear el form_tag dentro de la vista y que me tome el controller.

Comment: @sandovalgus no entiendo a que te refieres con que te tome el controller. En teoría podría ser el mismo controller que ocupas actualmente para descargar el pdf entero. Si expones cual es el problema que estás teniendo actualmente  con tu implementación, sería más fácil ayudarte

Comment: Actualice la pregunta. saludos